# Trying to figure out why code won't render list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to make a page that renders all of the posts that I have on a mongodb server with the code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            posts: []
        }
        this.listPosts = this.listPosts.bind(this);
    }
componentDidMount() {
        showAllPosts().then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            this.setState({
                posts: res
            })
        })
        console.log(this.state)
}
    listPosts() {
        this.state.posts.map(post =>
            <listPost data={post}/>)
    }
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> All Posts </h1>
                <ul class="mad-list">
                    {this.listPosts}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

As you can see, I console.log() the state after it was set and outside of the function, but the second console.log shows an empty array, so I'm sure there is something wrong with the way I am setting the state with this. I read that you should create a variable outside the function called that or self and set it to this and use it for the .setState function, but I tried that and it still didn't work. I am pretty sure there being no posts is what's stopping my listPosts function from working.

Comment: you forgot to run the function: `{this.listPosts()}`

Comment: React Component names need to be capitalized: `ListPost`

Comment: the second `console.log(this.state)` is actually run first, before `showAllPosts()` can do anything and it always logs the initial state: `{ posts: [] }`

Comment: On top of what marzelin mentioned, you also forgot the 'return' from listPosts(). I would consider Creative Joe's answer though as it's more idomatic React.

Comment: ```
class ListPost extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   username: '',
   title: '',
   bodytext: ''
  }
 }

 componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
   username: this.props.data.username,
   title: this.props.data.title,
   bodytext: this.props.data.bodytext
  })
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <div>
    <h1>{this.state.title}</h1>
    <h2>{this.state.username}</h2>
    <p>{this.state.bodytext}</p>
   </div>
   )
 }
}

export default ListPost;

Comment: I am trying to render a list of posts that people have made, but when I try to make a list of components called ListPost components, they won't render or show up.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do this could be

```
render() {
 const {posts} = this.state;
 let listPosts = (
  posts.map(post => <listPost data={post}/>)
 );
 return (
  <div>
   <h1> All Posts </h1>
   <ul class="mad-list">
    {listPosts}
   </ul>
  </div>
 )
}
```

I would explain what I did here.
So on the **const {posts}** line, I extracted posts from your state and stored it in a variable.

Also, I saved the map in a variable that you could use directly in your JSX code.

I called the variable I created in your JSX to render contents.

This way your function **listPosts** isn't needed anymore unless there is something you want to do other than looping through your result

Comment: When I changed everything to what you told me, it still doesn't print out any ListPost component inside the ul component that I have listPosts in. Could you think of any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: Do you have ListPost as a component that you imported or declared in this component?